# Rails: Remote form in popup window not calling controller action

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, put

I'm writing a time tracking app. I have a `Project` model that has a `time_logged` attribute.

I'm using a remote form -- rendered in a popup window -- to log time against a user. A jQuery event handler assigns the time tracked (in secs) to a hidden field in the form upon submit. All of the JS is being executed correctly.

The controller is supposed to call a method which logs the time tracked against a project selected in the form, but the projects never get updated. I'm thinking either the form isn't correctly calling the controller action or there's something wrong with how I've written the controller.

But I can't figure out what. I'll include the relevant code snippets below.

**projects_controller.rb**

```
respond_to :html, :js

  def track
    @project = Project.new 
  end 

  def log_time
    @project = Project.find(params[:project][:id])
    @project.increment_time_logged(project_log_time_params.to_i)
  end

  private 

    def project_params
      params.require(:project).permit(:id, :name, :fee, :client_id)
    end

    def project_log_time_params
      params.require(:project).permit(:time_logged)
    end
```

**project.rb**

```
  def increment_time_logged(number_of_seconds)
    self.time_logged += number_of_seconds
  end
```

**routes.rb**

```
  match '/projects/track-time', to: 'projects#track', via: 'get'
  match '/projects/log-time', to: 'projects#log_time', via: 'put'
```

**_track_time_form.html.erb**

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "track.js.erb" %>
<div id="countdown-timer"></div>
<div id="playback-button">&#9658;</div>
<div id="track-time-form">
    <%= form_for @project, :url => "/projects/log-time", remote: true do |p| %>
        <ul>
            <li><%= p.label :project, "Project:"%><br>
            <%= p.collection_select(:id, current_user.projects, :id, :name) %></li>

            <%= p.hidden_field :time_logged, :value => 0 %> <!-- value set by script in log_time.js.erb -->

            <li><%= p.submit "Log time", id: "log-time-button" %></li>
        </ul>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

**track.js.erb**

```
//initialise form 
timeTrackingForm = window.open("", "", "height=700,width=500");
$(timeTrackingForm.document.body).html("<%= j render( :partial => 'track_time_form' ) %>");

//assign variables 
var timer = $("#countdown-timer", $(timeTrackingForm.document));
var playbackControls = $("#playback-button", $(timeTrackingForm.document));
var form = $("#track-time-form", $(timeTrackingForm.document));
var actual_form = $("#new_project", $(timeTrackingForm.document)); 
var formUl = $("#track-time-form ul", $(timeTrackingForm.document));
var formLi = $("#track-time-form li", $(timeTrackingForm.document));
var logTimeButton = $("#log-time-button", $(timeTrackingForm.document));
var hidden = $("input:hidden", $(timeTrackingForm.document));
var timerPaused;

//initialise timer 
$(timeTrackingForm.document).ready(function(){
    initialiseTimer();
    style();
    $(playbackControls).click(function() {
        playOrPause();
    });
    $(actual_form).submit(function(){ 
        $(timer).timer('pause');
        timerPaused = true;
        var secondsTracked = $(timer).data('seconds');
        $(hidden).val(secondsTracked);
        resetTimerDisplay();
    }); 
});

function initialiseTimer() {
    $(timer).timer({
        format: '%H:%M:%S'
    });
    $(timer).timer('pause');
    timerPaused = true;
}

function resetTimerDisplay() {
    $(timer).timer('reset');
}

function style() {
    $(timer).css({'color':'black','font-size':'50px', 'margin':'auto', 'width':'180px'});
    $(playbackControls).css({'color':'#290052', 'font-size':'50px', 'margin':'auto', 'width':'55px'});
    $(form).css({'width':'300px','margin':'auto'});
    $(formUl).css({'list-style-type':'none'});
    $(formLi).css({'margin':'0 0 25px 0','font-sizeL':'18px','font-family':'Arial'});
    $(logTimeButton).css({'width':'180px','font-size':'18px','background-color':'green','color':'white','margin-top':'15px'});
}

function playOrPause() {
    if (timerPaused == true) {
        $(timer).timer('resume');
        timerPaused = false;
    }
    else {
        $(timer).timer('pause')
        timerPaused = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the `params` that are generated in the log on form submit? I'm suspecting this line `@project.increment_time_logged(project_log_time_params.to_i)` is wrong.

Comment: @Pavan There aren't any generated. I thought this was normal because the request is sent via AJAX?

Comment: @Pavan It looks like the controller action `log_time` isn't called at all. I added `puts "log_time has been called"` to the method, but this wasn't printed out in the server logs at all. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have an issue with your model. Currently you are only changing the attribute, but not saving the record to the database.

Change this

```
 def increment_time_logged(number_of_seconds)
    self.time_logged += number_of_seconds
  end
```

To this:

```
 def increment_time_logged(number_of_seconds)
    self.time_logged += number_of_seconds
    self.save
 end
```

Or, if you want to skip active record validations, use this:

```
 def increment_time_logged(number_of_seconds)
    time = self.time_logged += number_of_seconds
    self.update_attribute(:time_logged, time)
 end
```

Comment: This was definitely a contributing factor, so thanks! Looks like the problem is that `log_time` isn't being called at all (see comments above). Any ideas?

Comment: Try this in your controller. You should't need strong params if you updating a specific attribute:  @project.increment_time_logged(params[:time_logged].to_i)

Comment: Would it not be @project.increment_time_logged(params[:project][:time_logged].to_i)? 

Either way, I tried both versions and no such luck :( I think the problem is that the controller action isn't being called at all. Do you have any idea why this is?

Comment: Hard to say, may change your form to <%= form_for @project, url: {action: "log_time"}, remote: true do |p| %> (and try rails panel for chrome to debug your controllers https://github.com/dejan/rails_panel)

Comment: No such luck with that change. Thanks, I'll take a look. :-)